# How to properly access Strings of 2D array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Solved**

I thought this would be a simple task, but I can't seem to figure out how to properly access elements of a 2D array in JavaScript.

The array was created by taking keys and values from an object:

```
uassPairs.push(value);
uassPairs[uassPairs.indexOf(value)][1] = key;
```

^That occurred within a `$.each` loop.

Let's say that at `uassPairs[0][0]` I have the String `"foo"` stored. If I run `alert(uassPairs[0]);`, it displays `foo` to the screen.

However, if I try to access `"foo"` via `uassPairs[0][0]`, only the first character of the string is displayed: `f`.

Additionally, trying to access `uassPairs[i][1]` (where `i` is some index), I again only receive the first letter of that string - to clarify, the string stored in the index 1 column. The `arr[i][j]` format is how I've seen most folks handling arrays here.

**How do I access the entire string, not just a single character?**

Thank you.

**Edit:** thank you to dandavis, the correct syntax is `arr[0, 0]`, not `arr[0][0]`. Cheers.

Comment: `I again only receive the first letter` `uassPairs` is apparently a 1D array, so `uassPairs[0][0]` displays the first character of the first element.

Comment: And what the question?

Comment: just use one backet, not two.

Comment: You are pushing an element to an array, don't really understand what do You wanna achieve, but `uassPairs.push(value);` is what makes it 1D array.

Comment: Some good reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: You're trying to put an object (the key) in the array where a string character would be. But String are immutable so first of all it can't even go in there. As well as I think you need to read up on how multidimensional array indexing works, and how strings are stored and accessed as arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently

```
uassPairs[uassPairs.indexOf(value)]
```

returns `value` again. So if `value` was a string then another index acces like `[1]` returns the character at the specified position.

The strange thing is that it looks as if you were allowed to assign something to that position. However, there is no assignment, so a read access again returns the character.